# ios replace data value in a url

Tags: objective-c, ios, replace, nsstring

I have a string that I use as url to a uiwebview with some values sent to the server

```
NSString* myString = @"http://mywebsite.com?value1=10&value2=20&value3=30"
```

now I wish to obtain an array or a list with the values with name/value... how can I do this?

Comment: why downvote? at least a comment about the downvote..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`NSString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) has a method for this: `componentsSeparatedByString:`. Call it once, using "`&`" as the separator, then again using `?`. You can figure out the rest of the logic, I'm sure.